# How to add page number using Ajax, Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have the problem: there is a script for asyncronous page changing and loading using Jquery (Ajax):

```
        $('.page_button').live('click',function() {

            $('#ajaxBusy').show();
            $('.selected_page_button').attr('class','page_button');
            $(this).attr('class','selected_page_button');
            $.post("http://"+document.location.host+"/index.php/welcome/update_records_set/"+this.id,
            function(data)
            {
                if (data != "") 
                {
                    $(".records_content:last").empty();
                    $(".records_content").html(data);           
                }
                $('#ajaxBusy').hide();
            });
        });
```

This code works, but I also need to add "#page" for URL without refreshing. Also, I use CodeIgniter for developing, and this function from some controller loads a page:

```
public function language_testing($language_code) {
//some actions
}
```

But how can I extract page number from "`http://some_site/controller/en#5`" in order to load fifth page? Is there standard way for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean you want to get hash value from url then you could do:

```
var hassh = window.location.hash;
var hashVal = hassh.substr(1, hassh.length);
console.log( hashVal );
```

and if you want it from url then:

```
var url = "http://some_site/controller/en#5".split("#");
console.log( url[1] );
```

You can set hash like:

```
window.location.hash = "#yourValue";
```

Did you mean something like that

Comment: Can I set hash value? Or I can get it only?